# Flicker, orkut, picasa API for Flex? Need API?Please help?

Tags: flash, actionscript-3, flex3, flex4

I have to work on one new project, there we have to provide an option to download images from any website like, Orkut, picasa etc, so that the user, can view his/her pictures any time and his/her images are accessible any time, so i heard of APIs, that we developer can use.

i hope u r getting me, i saw tour de flex, there are few available API like for Flicker, they have ready made API, but i need to work on Facebook, Picasso, Photobucket, etc

please if any body of you having any solution on this, then plzz help me out,

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 0):

You may try [Picasa Flex AP](http://code.google.com/p/picasa-flex-api/) for picasa.